# I wanted the java program which can open a Open With dialog box in windows, Mac and Linux?

Tags: java, windows, macos, popup, javafx

As I have got the java program for opening Open with dialog Box for windows as follow :-

> File file = new File("D:/new.txt");
>
> ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("RUNDLL32.EXE",
>   "SHELL32.DLL,OpenAs_RunDLL", file.getAbsolutePath());
>
> ```
>     builder.redirectErrorStream();
>     builder.redirectOutput();
>     Process process = builder.start();
>     process.waitFor();
> ```

But I want my code to work in Mac as well as Linux ???
Please give a needfull reply and link ?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html

Answer (score 0):

You can choose JFileChooser, java class that internally call that in all platform. Example

[JFileChooser (JavaDoc)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html)

```
JFileChooser jfc= new JFileChooser() //You can choose the current directory or filesystemview
jfc.showOpenDialog() //or showSaveDialog(), it chooses the title of dialog and the viewform
jfc.getSelectedFile() //or Files[], get the value put on saving or file select in opening
```

You can select filter (by extension, by name, etc.)
Tell me your results!

Comment: @user3103829 Why? Tell me more

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Popup method to create a dialog in JavaFX which will work on Linux as well as mac

```
   public void popup() {
            final Stage dialog = new Stage();
            dialog.setTitle("Confirmation");
            Button yes = new Button("Yes");
            Button no = new Button("No");

            Label displayLabel = new Label("What do you want to do ?");
            displayLabel.setFont(Font.font(null, FontWeight.BOLD, 14));

            dialog.initModality(Modality.NONE);
            dialog.initOwner((Stage) tableview.getScene().getWindow());

            HBox dialogHbox = new HBox(20);
            dialogHbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

            VBox dialogVbox1 = new VBox(20);
            dialogVbox1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);

            VBox dialogVbox2 = new VBox(20);
            dialogVbox2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);

            dialogHbox.getChildren().add(displayLabel);
            dialogVbox1.getChildren().add(yes);
            dialogVbox2.getChildren().add(no);

            yes.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED,
                    new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                        @Override
                        public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                            // inside here you can use the minimize or close the previous stage//
                            dialog.close();
                        }
                    });
            no.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED,
                    new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                        @Override
                        public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                            dialog.close();
                        }
                    });

            dialogHbox.getChildren().addAll(dialogVbox1, dialogVbox2);
            Scene dialogScene = new Scene(dialogHbox, 500, 40);
            dialogScene.getStylesheets().add("//style sheet of your choice");
            dialog.setScene(dialogScene);
            dialog.show();
        }
```